# Exclude some type from XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a class has a property need to be serialized with some specified type.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
     private object _data;

     //[Any magic attribute here to exclude some types while serialization?]
     public object Data
     {
         get { return _data;}
         set { _data = value; }
     }
}

[Serializable]
public class A
{}

[Serializable]
public class B
{}


MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

In some cases I have:

```
myClass.Data = A;
```

In some cases I have:

```
myClass.Data = B;
```

And then I do serialization for MyClass. 
My question is: how can I serialize class B but class A as Data property inside MyClass?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: One thing - the code as written won't work anyway as you have declared `Data` as private...can you also clarify "how can I serialize class B but class A" - do you mean serialize class B but *not* class A?

Comment: I had modified my code Stephen. Yes, I want to Serialize class B but not class A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the ShouldSerialize Pattern:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Bar")]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeBar()
    {
        return (Bar > 10);
    }
}
```

The property 'Bar' will be serialized if it's greater than 10, otherwise, it won't.

Just create a boolean method with 'ShouldSerialize' in front of your property name. If the boolean then returns false, the property wil not be serialized.

More specific to your situation:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Foo))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Bar))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Foo")]
public class FooBar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Data")]
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeData()
    {
        return (Data.GetType() == typeof(Foo));
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Bar")]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Foo")]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You save my time JssDwt. I had tried to implement ShouldSerialize pattern in my code and it's work as expected.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help, you're the first person I helped on this forum, awesome!

Comment: One question more? If I have a List of FooBar as a property, and I want to exclude element FooBar if Foo.Bar = -1 when serialize. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this in your serializer? Why don't you just filter the list?

Comment: Because, in some cases, I don't need to serialize some items of that list. Did you have any proposal?

Comment: I would simply filter the list before you serialize it. If you don't want to serialize the items 'in some cases' you probably don't want any extra serialization logic in your class anyway.
If you do want to do it with serialization, you will have to write your own XML serializer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx

You can add [XmlIgnoreAttribute] attributte to your Data property, and optionally (if (Data is B) ..) remove it with newly created XmlAttributes. Then you use new XmlSerializer with edited behaviour.

Edit: Example:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class B : A { }

public class C : A { }

[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(C))]
public class D 
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public string Test = "Test";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new D();
        d.Data = new B() { Text = "Data" };
        var xSer = CreateOverrider(d);
        xSer.Serialize(new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("D:\\testB.xml")), d);
    }

    public static XmlSerializer CreateOverrider(D d)
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

        attrs.XmlIgnore =  d.Data is B;  
        xOver.Add(typeof(D), "Data", attrs);

        XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(D), xOver);
        return xSer;
    }
}
```

For B you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Test>Test</Test>
</D>
```

For C:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Test>Test</Test>
  <Data xsi:type="C">
    <Text>Data</Text>
  </Data>
</D>
```

Comment: Sorry MilanG, but XmlIgnore attribute will exclude Data property from serialization. My question is to include Data property but with type B only, if Data is type A, it will be null when serialized.

Comment: Thanks MilanG for posting your code to solve my problem. I think your solution works as promise. But I am using generic type serialization. And I shouldn't do check the type to be excluded at the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[XmlIgnore] attribute class

namespace System.Xml.Serialization

use XmlSerializer Class to serialize